# Does "but" means "and" or "or" in this context?

Tags: logic

I have to convert this statement into a logical expression:
"A, B, C will go to the theater if D doesn't come, but if A and B doesn't go then D will go if C goes to the theater"

My solution to this is $((A \land B \land C)\iff(\lnot D)) \lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B \land (D \implies C))$

Most sources I've found said that "but" is generally equivalent to "and", but it isn't really appropriate here IMO, because the original statement is describing 2 different cases that can happen. So, does "but" mean "and" or "or" in this context?

Comment: Here "but" means "and". In point of fact, I don't think there is an instance in English where "but" means "or".

Comment: In most cases "but" effectively means "and", *but* the reality is more nuanced. For example, if we say "$p$ but $q$", we really are saying "$p$ and $q$, despite the possibility that $p\to \neg q$". I.e; $p\wedge q\wedge (p\not\to \neg q)$